# using codeigniter,admin wants to approve user's registration request. But itsn't happening properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin

here is my controller page..

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class ApproveUser extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/Approve_Model');
  }
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('admin/Approve_Model');
    $result['data']=$this->Approve_Model->getView();
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata('user_id')))
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/approveUser',$result);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
    }
    else{
        redirect(site_url('Pages/index'));
    }
  }
```

[while running the code, it is redirecting to my index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYPbL.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($this->session->userdata('user_id')))
{
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/approveUser',$result);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
else
{
    redirect(site_url('Pages/index'));
}
```